# How to combine similar rows of data into one in R?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataset as shown in the first table below. I would like to create a new dataframe that combines different versions of the same item (i.e. "googleV1" and "googleV2" are combined) and adds (quantity, revenue fields) or averages (ratings field) the numbers associated so that it reads as just a single line item. The second table below illustrates my desired output. How would I go about combining and adding/averaging values as such? Thank you in advance!

I would like the solution to apply for when there may be multiple columns that work like the "group" column. I would also like to refer to the columns "quantity", "revenue", and "rating" by column number.

| item | group | quantity | revenue | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| googleV1 | blue | 4525 | $523513 | 94% |
| googleV2 | blue | 2452 | $134134 | 82% |
| 123V5 | red | 3563 | $134134 | 82% |
| 123V6 | red | 34534 | $2345 | 34% |
| 123V7 | yellow | 4574 | $34535 | 64% |

| item | group | quantity | revenue | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | blue | 6977 | $657647 | 88% |
| 123 | red | 38097 | $136479 | 58% |
| 123 | yellow | 4574 | $34535 | 64% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may remove the substring in the first column and then do a group by summarise approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(item = str_remove(item, "V\\d+$")) %>% 
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity), 
   revenue = str_c("$", sum(as.numeric(str_remove(revenue, fixed("$"))))), 
    rating = str_c(mean(readr::parse_number(rating)), "%"), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  item   quantity revenue rating
  <chr>     <int> <chr>   <chr> 
1 123       42671 $171014 60%   
2 google     6977 $657647 88%
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(item = c("googleV1", "googleV2", "123V5", "123V6", 
"123V7"), quantity = c(4525L, 2452L, 3563L, 34534L, 4574L),
 revenue = c("$523513", 
"$134134", "$134134", "$2345", "$34535"), rating = c("94%", "82%", 
"82%", "34%", "64%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I realized I left out one of my constraints. I will update accordingly. I need exactly what you did but with additional columns are have characters that will specify how it gets grouped together. I'm thinking it would just be a small adjustment to the `group_by` statement.

Comment: @piper180 if you have many grouping columns, use `group_by(item = str_remove(item, "V\\d+$"), across(yourcolname1:yourcolumnn))`

Comment: Thank you! What's the best format to refer to columns like "revenue" and "rating" using column numbers (df1[3], df1[5] type format)

Comment: @piper180 if the columns are in range you can use `revenue:othercol` or use `across(c(3, 5)`